# Proof involving gcd and congruence.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, congruences

So here is the statement:

$m \in \mathbb{N}  $ and $ a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$. Prove that $\gcd (a,m)=\gcd(b,m)$ iff there are solutions to the linear congruences  $ax\equiv b\,(\text{mod}\,\, m)$ and $by\equiv a\,(\text{mod}\,\, m)$.

I tried applying the definition of congruence and rearranging to get $ax-my=b$ and $by-mx=a$ and know that $\gcd(a,m)\big|\,b$ and $\gcd(b,m)\big|\,a$ but I'm stuck from here.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You don't have $ax-my=b$ and $by-mx=a$ but instead $ax-mk=b$ and $by-ml=a$ for some $k,l\in\mathbb Z$. $k,l$ needn't be $y,x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:

$$ax \equiv b \pmod m \implies ax + m(-s) = b$$
$$by \equiv a \pmod m \implies by + m(-t) = a$$

From the Bezout's Lemma we have that $(a,m)\mid b$ from the first one and $(b,m)\mid a$ from the second. Now if $(b,m)=p_1p_2...p_k$ then $p_1p_2...p_k \mid m$. From the claim above we have $p_1p_2...p_k \mid a$. Hence $p_1p_2...p_k \mid (a,m) \implies (b,m) \mid (a,m)$. Working other way around we have: $(a,m) \mid (b,m)$. From this we have that $(a,m) = (b,m)$

Now assume that $(a,m) = (b,m)$

Then from Bezout's Lemma $ax + my = d$, has solutions if d is a multiple of $(a,m)$ Hence if we set $d$ as $b$ we have: $(a,m) = (b,m) \mid b$ and the equation has a solution. Prove simularly for the other equation.

Comment: @user314 Just a typo. Note: $s,t$ are any natural numbers.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint ($\boldsymbol{\Leftarrow}$):** $\gcd(a,m)\mid b$ and $\gcd(a,m)\mid m$ implies $\gcd(a,m)\mid\gcd(b,m)$.

**Hint ($\boldsymbol{\Rightarrow}$):** [Bezout's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) says that there are $x,u$ so that $ax+mu=\gcd(a,m)$. Furthermore, there is an $s$ so that $s\gcd(b,m)=b$.

Comment: Does that mean you can use Bounds by divisibility to show that that gcd(a,m)<=gcd(b,m)and do the reverse to show they are equal?

Comment: I would use the fact that $a\mid b$ and $b\mid a$ shows that $a/b$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}$, and there are only a couple of those.

Comment: @Andrew749 Since $\gcd(\ldots)$ is [by definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) a positive integer, yes you can. But notice that if $a\mid b$ and $b\mid a$ and $a,b$ can be any integers, then you may have $-6\mid 6, 6\mid -6$ and $6\neq -6$. In general, $(a\mid b, b\mid a, a,b\in\mathbb Z)\implies |a|=|b|$. You can only claim that $|a|\le |b|$ if $a\mid b$ and $a,b$ are not necessarily positive integers.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align} 
\gcd(a,m) = \gcd(b,m) \overset{\rm\ \ Bezout}
\iff&\qquad a\Bbb Z\! +\! m\Bbb Z\ \ =\ \ b\Bbb Z\! +\! m\Bbb Z\\
\iff&\ b\in a\Bbb Z\! +\! m\Bbb Z,\ a\in b\Bbb Z\! +\! m\Bbb Z\\
\iff&\ b \equiv ax,\ \  {\rm and}\, \ \  a \equiv  by\!\!\pmod m,\ \ {\rm for\ some}\ \ x,y \end{align}$

**Remark** $\ $ The first equivalence uses the following form of Bezout's Theorem

$$ j\Bbb Z + k \Bbb Z\, =\, \gcd(j,k)\Bbb Z$$